# Laravel JOIN with JSON string

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have two tables in Laravel, one is the `comment` table, and the second is the `users` table. In the comment table, I have this type of data.

[image]

For this comment table, I want to match the `tags` column's userid in JSON, so how can we join that userid with the user's table? here is what I tried, but that is not working as expected.

```
$messages = TopicComment::where('user_id', $currentUserId)
    ->join("users", "users.id", "=", "users.id")
    ->(function ($query) {
        $query->whereJsonContains('tags.userid', users.id);
    })
    ->
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: is there a relationship with `User` defined on your `TopicComment` model?

Answer (score 0):

with this package you can create a relation via a json field
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

Answer (score 0):

First, there seem to be a number of errors in your code.

1. Judging from the DB schema, there is no `user_id` column in your comments table and so, `::where('user_id', $currentUserId)` will not work.
2. A similar issue occurs in your `join` statement. You're joining on `"users.id","=","users.id"` which is the same column in the same table.
3. There's no method called in the line with `function($query)`. Ideally, should be a `where` clause.
4. Correct usage of `whereJsonContains` would be:

```
$query->whereJsonContains('tags', ['userid' => $currentUserId]);
```

5. Rouge arrow after that line.

And so, your final result after correcting the changes should look like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
...

$messages = TopicComment::join('users', 'users.id', DB::Raw("CAST(comments.tags->'$.userid' AS UNSIGNED)"))
            ->where(function ($query) use ($currentUserId) {
                $query->whereJsonContains('tags', ['userid' => $currentUserId]);
            })
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

Comment: Tags is an array first, I don't think just using whereJsonContains will work.

Comment: @IdeatoCode thanks for pointing that out. There should be a way to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to extract is to use json tables.

```
DB::select(DB::raw("
    SELECT document_types.*, jst.name 
    FROM document_types, 
        JSON_TABLE(settings, '$[*]' COLUMNS (
            `userid` int(11) PATH '$.userid',
            `name` varchar(255) PATH '$.name'
        )) jst 
        inner join users on jst.userid = users.id WHERE users.id = :id"   
,['id' => $currentUserId]))->get()
```

credit: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306938/extract-json-object-inside-of-an-json-array-then-search-base-on-id

Unfortunately I don't have json functions on my mysql so the code will probably fail, maybe at least it'll help get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way...

eg:

```php
<?php
$comments = DB::table('topic_comments')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'topic_comments.tags->userid')
->select('topic_comments.*', 'users.name')
->get();
```